# Find the last class of an item and post data according to item clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I got three block elements on my homepage that each represent a service. When I click on a block a div slides open with tabs in it, these tabs represent the sub services of the clicked service block.

When a block is clicked I want it to show only the sub services of the serviceblock clicked.

My idea was to use the same classname on the block as the alias field in my database (with this field I can get all data, it's basically the title without spaces and quotes). This way I can post the classname with ajax to my query and only retrieve the data of the block clicked instead of everything at once.

But the problem is, I have multiple classes, how can I tell jquery which one to get? Or can I search for one? And how can I post this correctly to my php script?

I'll show what I got, maybe it makes it easier to understand:

(My blocks, notice the last classes of each div: haven, openbaar, landmeten)

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 vk-clear-padding handmouse haven">
    <div class="vk-iconbox vk-iconbox-background text-center" style="background-color: #ececec;">
        <div class="iconbox-content vk-section-style-5">
          <h2 class="vk-heading text-uppercase" aria-label="01">
              <span>Haven & Industrie</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 vk-clear-padding handmouse openbaar">
    <div class="vk-iconbox vk-iconbox-background vk-iconbox-striped text-center" style="background-color: #faf5f5;">
        <div class="iconbox-content vk-section-style-5">
          <h2 class="vk-heading text-uppercase" aria-label="02">
              <span>Openbare Ruimte</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 vk-clear-padding handmouse landmeten">
    <div class="vk-iconbox vk-iconbox-background text-center" style="background-color: #ececec;">
        <div class="iconbox-content vk-section-style-5">
          <h2 class="vk-heading text-uppercase" aria-label="03">
              <span>Landmeten</span>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript (only works for the first block at the moment):

```
$('.haven').click(function(e){
    $('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".tabwrapper").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

And my php script where the name identical to the alias (other name for title in my database) of the service must be posted to. I already added the line in my query under the name `dienstnaam`

```
<?
session_start();

class Connection {
    // Configure Database Vars
    private $host     = 'removed';
    private $username = 'removed';
    private $password = 'removed';
    private $db_name  = 'removed';
    public $db;

    function __construct() {
        // Create connection
        $db = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db_name);

        // Check connection
        if ($db->connect_errno > 0) {
            die('Unable to connect to the database: '.$db->connect_error);
        }

        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        $this->db->query('SET NAMES utf8');
        if (!$result = $this->db->query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function multi_query($query) {
        $db = $this->db;
        if (!$result = $this->db->multi_query($query)) {
            die('There was an error running the multi query ['.$db->error.']');
        } else {
            return $result;
        }

    }

    public function real_escape_string($value) {
        return $this->db->real_escape_string($value);
    }

    public function inserted_id() {
        return $this->db->insert_id;
    }
}

$conn = new Connection;

?>

<div class="vk-what-we-do-section vk-section vk-section-style-2 vk-section-style-3 tabwrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="vk-heading vk-heading-border vk-heading-border-left">
          <?
          //  Haal de categorienaam op
          $level1               = "SELECT * FROM `snm_categories` WHERE alias  = '".$_POST['dienstnaam']."'";
          $levelcon1              = $conn->query($level1);
          $levelcr1             = array();
          while ($levelcr1[]    = $levelcon1->fetch_array());

          //  Haal alle artikelen op bij de bovenstaande categorie
          $level2               = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE catid  = '".$conn->real_escape_string($levelcr1[0]['id'])."'";
          $levelcon2              = $conn->query($level2);
          $levelcr2             = array();
          while ($levelcr2[]    = $levelcon2->fetch_array());
          ?>
      <span>
        <span class="vk-text-color-yellow-1">Onze</span> expertise
      </span>
        </h2>
        <nav class="box-filter text-center clearfix">
            <ul class="vk-filter vk-filter-button-fix hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <?
                foreach($levelcr2 as $topnamen){
                  if($topnamen['id'] != ''){
                    $namenoverzicht .= '<li class="data-filter" data-filter=".'.$topnamen['alias'].'">'.$topnamen['title'].'</li>';
                  }
                }
                echo $namenoverzicht;
                ?>
            </ul>

            <select class="vk-filter vk-filter-button-fix form-control hidden-md hidden-lg" id="dropdown-filter">
              <?
              foreach($levelcr2 as $options){
                $optionlist .= '<option class="data-filter" value=".'.$options['alias'].'">'.$options['title'].'</option>';
              }
              echo $optionlist;
              ?>
            </select>
        </nav>

        <div class="row vk-filter-fix">
          <?
          $o = 1;
          foreach($levelcr2 as $tabdata){
            if($o == 1){
              $first = 'first';
            }else{
              $first = '';
            }
            $tabitem .= '
            <div class="item '.$first.' '.$tabdata['alias'].'">
                <div class="col-md-6 left">

                    <div class="vk-img-frame">
                        <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 right">
                    <div class="content">
                        <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">'.$tabdata['title'].'</h4>
                        '.$tabdata['introtext'].'
                    </div>
                    <div class="vk-buttons">
                        <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                        </div>
                        <a href="'.$tabdata['alias'].'.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
            $o++;
          }
          echo $tabitem;
          ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tested my code btw with the alias hardcoded in the query and it works. So I only need to know how to retrieve the classname from the div and then send it through ajax to my php script and then display the result of my php script on my index page inside a div called `tabwrapper`.

The source of my php script (with the alias hardcoded or else there wont be anything):

```
<div class="vk-what-we-do-section vk-section vk-section-style-2 vk-section-style-3 tabwrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="vk-heading vk-heading-border vk-heading-border-left">
                <span>
        <span class="vk-text-color-yellow-1">Onze</span> expertise
      </span>
        </h2>
        <nav class="box-filter text-center clearfix">
            <ul class="vk-filter vk-filter-button-fix hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                <li class="data-filter" data-filter=".landmeetkunde">Landmeetkunde</li><li class="data-filter" data-filter=".uitzetten">Uitzetten</li><li class="data-filter" data-filter=".monitoring">Monitoring</li><li class="data-filter" data-filter=".gis">GIS</li><li class="data-filter" data-filter=".as-built-verwerking">As-built verwerking</li><li class="data-filter" data-filter=".inspectie-metingen">Inspectie-metingen</li>            </ul>

            <select class="vk-filter vk-filter-button-fix form-control hidden-md hidden-lg" id="dropdown-filter">
              <option class="data-filter" value=".landmeetkunde">Landmeetkunde</option><option class="data-filter" value=".uitzetten">Uitzetten</option><option class="data-filter" value=".monitoring">Monitoring</option><option class="data-filter" value=".gis">GIS</option><option class="data-filter" value=".as-built-verwerking">As-built verwerking</option><option class="data-filter" value=".inspectie-metingen">Inspectie-metingen</option><option class="data-filter" value="."></option>            </select>
        </nav>

        <div class="row vk-filter-fix">

              <div class="item first landmeetkunde">
                  <div class="col-md-6 left">

                      <div class="vk-img-frame">
                          <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 right">
                      <div class="content">
                          <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">Landmeetkunde</h4>

                      </div>
                      <div class="vk-buttons">
                          <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                          </div>
                          <a href="landmeetkunde.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item  uitzetten">
                  <div class="col-md-6 left">

                      <div class="vk-img-frame">
                          <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 right">
                      <div class="content">
                          <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">Uitzetten</h4>

                      </div>
                      <div class="vk-buttons">
                          <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                          </div>
                          <a href="uitzetten.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item  monitoring">
                  <div class="col-md-6 left">

                      <div class="vk-img-frame">
                          <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 right">
                      <div class="content">
                          <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">Monitoring</h4>

                      </div>
                      <div class="vk-buttons">
                          <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                          </div>
                          <a href="monitoring.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item  gis">
                  <div class="col-md-6 left">

                      <div class="vk-img-frame">
                          <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 right">
                      <div class="content">
                          <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">GIS</h4>

                      </div>
                      <div class="vk-buttons">
                          <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                          </div>
                          <a href="gis.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item  as-built-verwerking">
                  <div class="col-md-6 left">

                      <div class="vk-img-frame">
                          <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 right">
                      <div class="content">
                          <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">As-built verwerking</h4>

                      </div>
                      <div class="vk-buttons">
                          <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                          </div>
                          <a href="as-built-verwerking.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item  inspectie-metingen">
                  <div class="col-md-6 left">

                      <div class="vk-img-frame">
                          <img src="images/services/image-7.jpg" alt=""/>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="col-md-6 right">
                      <div class="content">
                          <h4 class="text-uppercase vk-title">Inspectie-metingen</h4>

                      </div>
                      <div class="vk-buttons">
                          <div class="vk-counter vk-counter-non-icon">
                          </div>
                          <a href="inspectie-metingen.html" class="vk-btn vk-btn-transparent text-uppercase">MEER INFORMATIE
                              <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My previous ajax script as asked in the comments:

```
(function(){
/*
Meer websites laden
*/
  if(document.getElementById('loadnews') !== null) {
    var limit = 9;
    var offset = 0;
    var i =0;
    $('#loadmore').click(function() {
      limit = 3;
        if(i == 0) {
            offset += 9;
        } else {
            offset += 3;
        }
        i++;
      ajax();
    });

    var posts = document.getElementById('loadnews');

    function ajax() {
        $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/loadmore.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {limit: limit, offset: offset},
        success: function(data){
          var newWrapper = document.createElement('div')
            //add class to newWrapper or whatever
            newWrapper.innerHTML=data;
            loadnews.appendChild(newWrapper);
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#portfolio-gallery").lightGallery({
              galleryId: 2,
              selector: '.post-image'
            });
          }, 300);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
                  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                       alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
                   } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                       alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
                   } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                       alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
                   } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                       alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
                   } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                       alert('Time out error.');
                   } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                       alert('Ajax request aborted.');
                   } else {
                       alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
                   }
               }
        });
    }

    ajax();
  }
}());
```

Comment: where's tabwrapper element?

Comment: It's the top div in my phpscript under my connection class.

Comment: ok can you show output html as it appears (view source of page and copy that) - need to see structure in relation to your headers

Comment: Added it to my question @Pete I hardcoded the alias in the query though or else there wasn't any data.

Comment: The question is incredibly convoluted, the problem needs to be more specifically explained and the irrelevant parts of the code removed.

Comment: @twan, I can't see the tabwrapper in relation to haven in the source - what I am trying to find out is where the tabwrapper is in relation to the haven div.  If it is a direct child as dmitry suggests, then his answer is good to use, but if not then you will need to tweek the js

Comment: @Pete It is in the same file as my php script while the blocks are on my index. I want to load the entire file on my index when a block is clicked. So there can be 3 variations of data that is loaded in depending on the alias that is sent through ajax. The tabwrapper is the last class in the div below my connection class, I can see it here.

Comment: ok then, but you have no ajax call in your existing button click which is what was getting me confused

Comment: @Pete Correct, this was part of the question. How to first determine what block was clicked and send that value (the last classname) through ajax. My ajax is a little rusty.

Comment: @twan In that case, can you show what you've done so far in relation to AJAX? The only JS you included is all about hiding and showing elements.

Comment: @DmitryPonkin I only got an ajax call from a different script that I want to use here, but have a hard time understanding how to combine it with what I want. I will add it (but the question will get big and with irrelevant info)

Comment: Instead of using a class, use a data attribute then you only have to bind it to a common class, rather than binding it individually to different classes

Comment: Okay but even with a data attribute instead of a class I still need to know how to send it through ajax. I don't want three ajax calls for every attribute. I'm sure it can be done with 1.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, this should work:

```
$('.handmouse').click(function(e){
    $(this).children('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).children(".tabwrapper").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

**EDIT**: In case if `tabwrapper` is not a direct descendant of `handmouse`, then the following should work:

```
$('.handmouse').click(function(e){
    $(this).find('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).find(".tabwrapper").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

**EDIT:** Due to the question being much more complex than it should be, the above code is irrelevant. My last shot at understanding of what exactly is needed is this:

```
$('.handmouse').click(function(e){
    var classList = $(this).className.split(/\s+/);
    var alias = classList[classList.length]; // This is the... "alias"?... of the element that was clicked.
    // Fetch data using the alias into a 'data' variable
    $('.tabwrapper').slideToggle();
    $('.tabwrapper').text(data); // Put the hypothetical data into the tabwrapper.
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".tabwrapper").offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This opens the div no matterwhat class is clicked. I want to post different names according to the div clicked and then retrieve the correct data with it.

Comment: how do you know the tabwrapper is a direct child of the handmouse div?

Comment: @Pete Thanks, I added another option that would work with indirect children, though I'm having a hard time understanding what it has to do with posting and retrieving data.

Comment: hahaha, looks like it isn't a child at all!  From OP comments seems to be only one div somewhere on the page and they want to load in data when they do a slide toggle - really poor question

Comment: @Pete how does it look now?

Comment: @DmitryPonkin It's not that hard to understand lol, it's just a lot of code. I need to know which block was clicked and send data (the alias of the service block clicked) with ajax to my php script. and there in a query place the alias that was sent and get the correct data. Then display it back on my index, all with ajax. The first issue was getting the alias name (I wanted to use classnames for this but Pete reccomended data attributes)

Comment: @twan Well, my last edit provides a solution that would work with class names as is (which I do not recommend as well, but it should work). The only thing left there is fetch the data using the alias variable into the data variable and you're all set.